# how to search and update data into ms access

Tags: vb.net

my  problem is how to search data and update it in ms access and vb.net

my code:
    Imports System.Data.OleDb

```
Public Class Form5
  Dim provider As String
  Dim dataFile As String
  Dim connString As String
  Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
  Public dr As OleDbDataReader

  Private Sub Form5_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\project database\Database5.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString

  End Sub

  Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    myConnection.Open()
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
    TextBox5.Clear()
    TextBox6.Clear()
    TextBox7.Clear()
    TextBox8.Clear()
    TextBox9.Clear()
    TextBox10.Clear()
    TextBox11.Clear()

    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * FROM registration WHERE (Name = '" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read()
      TextBox2.Text = dr("No").ToString
      TextBox3.Text = dr("Name").ToString
      TextBox4.Text = dr("Age").ToString
      TextBox5.Text = dr("Gender").ToString
      TextBox6.Text = dr("Phone").ToString
      TextBox7.Text = dr("Address").ToString
      TextBox8.Text = dr("Desease").ToString
      TextBox9.Text = dr("RoomNo").ToString
      TextBox10.Text = dr("Building").ToString
      TextBox11.Text = dr("RoomType").ToString
    End While
    myConnection.Close()
  End Sub
End Class
```

the error I'm getting:

> "No value given for one or more required parameters."}

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Use an `If dr.Read()` if not needing to loop.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the issue here that when you click button3 you clear the textbox1 where I assume you type the name you wish to search. So its throwing you an error that there is nothing in that field. And even if you type something after wards, and click the button again, it will clear it again before it starts searching. so basically, you're searching for nothing.